# how to define a yasnippet in init file?

Tags: init-file, yasnippet

My init file (`.emacs`) is version-controlled, my packages are installed with [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package), so my Emacs config is self-contained.

I don't want to add (and manage) specific snippet files into my repository, so I wonder if there is a way to define snippets directly in my init file.

Comment: https://github.com/Kungsgeten/yankpad maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at `yas-define-snippets`?

```
yas-define-snippets is a compiled Lisp function in ‘yasnippet.el’.

(yas-define-snippets MODE SNIPPETS)

Define SNIPPETS for MODE.

SNIPPETS is a list of snippet definitions, each taking the
following form

 (KEY TEMPLATE NAME CONDITION GROUP EXPAND-ENV LOAD-FILE KEYBINDING UUID SAVE-FILE)

Within these, only KEY and TEMPLATE are actually mandatory.

TEMPLATE might be a Lisp form or a string, depending on whether
this is a snippet or a snippet-command.
```